# Binding Dictionary<,>.Keys.Count to a Label

Tags: c#, binding, dictionary

I have a Dictionary and want to display the number of items in this dictionary with a Label, without updating the label manually each time I add or remove an item from the dictionary.

I tried it with the Binding class:

```
Binding bindingNodeCount = new Binding("Text", _graphDisplay.data.nodes.Keys, "Count");
labelNumberOfNodes.DataBindings.Add(bindingNodeCount);
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to bind the "Count"-Property (at least it throws me an argument exception, saying he can't bind the Property Count to the DataSource).

Is there an other method to automatically update the display of the Item-Count of my Dictionary?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't going to work, on multiple levels:

- you can't bind to properties of containers (such as `Keys`) - it assumes you want the first item from the container (i.e. `.Keys[0].Count`)
- dictionary doesn't provide notification events

To do what you want, you would probably have to have your own dictionary implementation (or subclass) with notofication events, *and* manually propagate that a higher-level object (`data` or `graphDisplay`) as a facade property, *and* forward the event.

It will be easier to just update it manually, I suspect.

Comment: Agreed, seems like a long way for a shortcut.

Comment: Yap, I solved it by firing an event, when the dictionary is changed and consume this event in my form.